# How to show a multi line cell in a tableview in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a table (TableView) that acts as a receipt. The table consists of 3 columns, product, total price and the type of payment. 
In the product column, I have an arraylist that contains the name of each product, the price of each product and the number of each product.
When a user selects a specific date from the DatePicker and clicks the button "Show today's sales", the table will show the sale for that specific day.

The problem is that the entire Arraylist is printed in one line in the cell, but it is supposed that each index in the arraylist must be printed on a line (which contains of product name, product price and number of product).

It should look like this:
[image]

I know there are some questions which looks similar, but the difference is that in this case I want to insert a whole arraylist in a cell and it should be printed on multiple lines. This specific question has not been answered earlier.

Here is my code so far:

```
package gui;

import container.Container;
import controller.Controller;
import model.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

// this class extends GridPane because it is a Javafx tab
public class Todays_sales extends GridPane {


    Controller controller = Controller.getInstance();

    Container container = Container.getInstance();
    private DatePicker dpDate;
    private TableView<Sale> table = new TableView<>();
    private ObservableList<Sale> data;

    public Todays_sales () {

        setGridLinesVisible(false);
        setPadding(new Insets(20));
        setHgap(10);
        setVgap(10);

        // date
        dpDate = new DatePicker();
        this.add(dpDate, 0, 0);
        dpDate.setEditable(false);

        // button for today's sales
        Button btnShowTodaysSales = new Button("Show today's sales");
        this.add(btnShowTodaysSales , 0, 1);
        btnShowTodaysSales.setOnAction(event -> showTodaysSales_Action());

        // product
        TableColumn<Sale, String> productCol = new TableColumn<>("Product");
        productCol .setMinWidth(350);
        productCol .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Sale, String>("name_price_number"));
        table.getColumns().add(productCol);

        // total price
        TableColumn<Sale, Integer> totalPriceCol = new TableColumn<>("Total price");
        totalPriceCol.setMinWidth(100);
        totalPriceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Sale, Integer>("totalprice"));
        table.getColumns().add(totalPriceCol);

        // type of payment
        TableColumn<Sale, String> paymentTypeCol = new TableColumn<>("Payment type");
        paymentTypeCol.setMinWidth(150);
        paymentTypeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Sale, String>("paymentType"));
        table.getColumns().add(paymentTypeCol);

        this.add(table, 0, 4);

    }

    private void showTodaysSales_Action() {
        if (dpDate.getValue() != null) {

            data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(controller.getTodaysSales(dpDate.getValue()));
            table.setItems(data);

        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Today's sale");
            alert.setHeaderText("");
            alert.setContentText("A date must be selected");
            alert.show();
        }

    }

}
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According that  *name_price_number* is a String array already you can just replace
this line:

```
    productCol .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Sale, String>("name_price_number"));
```

with custom cell value factory
which may look like this for example

```
  productCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
        String result = String.join("\n",param.getValue().getName_price_number());
        return new SimpleStringProperty(result);
    });
```

In this factory you just concatenate your array with a new line delimeter and 
return as a javaFX StringProperty